# Opening up new page with Intents Android

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to switch over to my new page when I tap on one of the `ListItems` on my ListView using `Intents`. However, I keep getting the error :

`Unfortunately, ToDoApp has stopped`

I'm not quite sure how to use the debugger yet but this is what I have so far.

```
public class ToDoActivity extends Activity {
    private ArrayList<String> todoItems;        
    private ArrayAdapter<String> todoAdapter; // declare array adapter which will translate the piece of data to teh view
    private ListView lvItems; // attach to lsitview
    private EditText etNewItem;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_to_do);
        etNewItem = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNewItem);
        lvItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvItems); // now we have access to ListView
        //populateArrayItems();  // call function
        readItems(); // read items from file
        todoAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, todoItems); //create adapter
        lvItems.setAdapter(todoAdapter); // populate listview using the adapter 
        //todoAdapter.add("item 4");
        setupListViewListener();
        setupEditItemListener();
    }

    private void launchEditItem() {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, EditItemActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    private void setupEditItemListener() { // on click, run this function to display edit page
        lvItems.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                launchEditItem();
            }
        });
    }

    private void setupListViewListener() {
        lvItems.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View item, int pos, long id) {
                todoItems.remove(pos);
                todoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // has adapter look back at the array list and refresh it's data and repopulate the view
                writeItems();   
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.to_do, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onAddedItem(View v) {
        String itemText = etNewItem.getText().toString();
        todoAdapter.add(itemText); // add to adapter
        etNewItem.setText(""); //clear edit text
        writeItems(); //each time to add item, you want to write to file to memorize
    }

    private void readItems() {
        File filesDir = getFilesDir(); //return path where files can be created for android
        File todoFile = new File(filesDir, "todo.txt");
        try {
            todoItems = new ArrayList<String>(FileUtils.readLines(todoFile)); //populate with read
        }catch (IOException e) { // if files doesn't exist  
            todoItems = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
    }

    private void writeItems() {
        File filesDir = getFilesDir();  //return path where files can be created for android
        File todoFile = new File(filesDir, "todo.txt");
        try {
            FileUtils.writeLines(todoFile, todoItems); // pass todoItems to todoFile
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I thought running the function `setupEditItemListener()` would open up to my new `Activity` but it does not do so. Could someone help point out where I have gone wrong? Thanks!

Console output:

```
[2013-12-07 20:39:05 - ToDoApp] ------------------------------
[2013-12-07 20:39:05 - ToDoApp] Android Launch!
[2013-12-07 20:39:05 - ToDoApp] adb is running normally.
[2013-12-07 20:39:05 - ToDoApp] Performing com.example.todoapp.ToDoActivity activity launch
[2013-12-07 20:39:05 - ToDoApp] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'NexusS'
[2013-12-07 20:39:05 - ToDoApp] Uploading ToDoApp.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2013-12-07 20:39:05 - ToDoApp] Installing ToDoApp.apk...
[2013-12-07 20:39:05 - ToDoApp] Success!
[2013-12-07 20:39:05 - ToDoApp] Starting activity com.example.todoapp.ToDoActivity on device emulator-5554
[2013-12-07 20:39:06 - ToDoApp] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.todoapp/.ToDoActivity }
```

LogCat:

```
12-08 16:03:33.854: D/dalvikvm(2012): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
12-08 16:03:33.884: D/dalvikvm(2012): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 37K, 6% free 2641K/2808K, paused 0ms, total 0ms
12-08 16:03:33.894: I/dalvikvm-heap(2012): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.307MB for 635808-byte allocation
12-08 16:03:33.914: D/dalvikvm(2012): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 6% free 3259K/3432K, paused 19ms, total 19ms
12-08 16:03:33.924: D/AndroidRuntime(2012): Shutting down VM
12-08 16:03:33.924: W/dalvikvm(2012): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2ec4648)
12-08 16:03:33.924: E/AndroidRuntime(2012): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-08 16:03:33.924: E/AndroidRuntime(2012): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.todoapp/com.example.todoapp.ToDoActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Don't call setOnClickListener for an AdapterView. You probably want setOnItemClickListener instead
12-08 16:03:33.924: E/AndroidRuntime(2012):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
12-08 16:03:33.924: E/AndroidRuntime(2012):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
12-08 16:03:33.924: E/AndroidRuntime(2012):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-08 16:03:33.924: E/AndroidRuntime(2012):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
12-08 16:03:33.924: E/AndroidRuntime(2012):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-08 16:03:33.924: E/AndroidRuntime(2012):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-08 16:03:33.924: E/AndroidRuntime(2012):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
12-08 16:03:33.924: E/AndroidRuntime(2012):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-08 16:03:33.924: E/AndroidRuntime(2012):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-08 16:03:33.924: E/AndroidRuntime(2012):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
12-08 16:03:33.924: E/AndroidRuntime(2012):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-08 16:03:33.924: E/AndroidRuntime(2012):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-08 16:03:33.924: E/AndroidRuntime(2012): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Don't call setOnClickListener for an AdapterView. You probably want setOnItemClickListener instead
12-08 16:03:33.924: E/AndroidRuntime(2012):     at android.widget.AdapterView.setOnClickListener(AdapterView.java:773)
12-08 16:03:33.924: E/AndroidRuntime(2012):     at com.example.todoapp.ToDoActivity.setupEditItemListener(ToDoActivity.java:52)
12-08 16:03:33.924: E/AndroidRuntime(2012):     at com.example.todoapp.ToDoActivity.onCreate(ToDoActivity.java:41)
12-08 16:03:33.924: E/AndroidRuntime(2012):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
12-08 16:03:33.924: E/AndroidRuntime(2012):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
12-08 16:03:33.924: E/AndroidRuntime(2012):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
12-08 16:03:33.924: E/AndroidRuntime(2012):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Now is an opportune time to learn how to use the debugger!

Comment: @RickFalck would you know a good resource for a debugger tutorial?

Comment: Not really.  My experience with debugging tools from previous languages/platforms makes it easy for me to see how the next one works.  They all have the same basic way to set break-points and see the variables when you are stopped at a break-point.  Android has LogCat, which is a lot like using System.out.println() in a java console program to output data instead of tracing it.

Comment: In your case, learning to read the Exception output would help.  The answer is on the first line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe consider replacing the call

`setOnClickListener(..)`

with

`setOnItemClickListener(..)`

your call to these implements an anonymous listener class, so this change may require changing listener interface name, method signatures.

You can see a suggestion to do this in the stacktrace at

*RuntimeException: Don't call setOnClickListener for an AdapterView. You probably want setOnItemClickListener instead*

Answer (score 1):

The answer was in your logcat only. Do make a habit to go through logcat :-

```
12-08 16:03:33.924: E/AndroidRuntime(2012): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.todoapp/com.example.todoapp.ToDoActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Don't call setOnClickListener for an AdapterView. You probably want setOnItemClickListener instead
```

use `setOnItemClick` listener and start your activity in it

Answer (score 1):

you are using a wrong listener for list item. It must me **"onItemClickListener"**

```
private void setupEditItemListener() {
lvItems.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // TODO Do anything you want to do here... 
    }
});
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Dude , you created a custom function and in those function you wrote listview listeners. Just by calling them these listeners won't fire.

Simply write the listeners in `onCreate()` without the custom functions. It will work. Moreover, you app stopped. Please make it a habit to post the stack trace to see the errors. Maybe it is a null pointer exception coming up on some line. It usually is the cause of app crash.

Comment: If I comment out `launchEditItem` and `setupEditItemListener`, my app would work in the extend of being able to delete items in the list on `LongClick` and also being able to add items to the list. I was trying to create something similar using Intents. I'm not quite sure where the trace stack is. I looked it up online and I was told it is in the console but it doesn't provide me with much but I'll post it on the question

Comment: dude the logcat window is stack trace. Run your app again. make it crash by doing the same scenario. See the LogCatWindow. Copy all of the error in RED lines(paragraph). Paste it here in code tags

Comment: I posted teh LogCat, but I'm not sure how to get teh ...11 more to display